# Determine App User's Domain / Google Customer_ID

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-apps-marketplace

I have a Marketplace app on GAE that gets correctly installed and authenticated using a service account.  When a new domain admin installs the app, I capture the admin's email address so that I can impersonate him/her with any Admin SDK calls I need.  Works great.

Now when a non-admin user of my new customer begins to use my app, how do I determine which customer (google apps) they belong to?  While I might know the domain (via the user's email address) this can't be the best method - as my customer (Google Apps customer) may utilize more than one domain in their account.  Is there a way to determine the customer_ID associated to the user's Google App account?

Is there a standard workflow established for this sort of thing?  I know I could, upon successful installation of my app, iterate through all of my customer's current users to find all domains associated with them - but if subsequent domains are added post-install this won't be guaranteed to work.  Do I need to subscribe to Users.watch via the directory API in order to watch for new domains?  Seems like a lot of work if there's an easier method.

Answer (score 1):

You should have access to the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile" scope when you build an application for the Google Apps marketplace.

When you make a call to the People: get Api for the loggedin user, then you see a field "domain" that displays the Google Apps domain. From the docs :

> domain : The hosted domain name for the user's Google Apps account.
>   For instance, example.com. The plus.profile.emails.read or email scope
>   is needed to get this domain name.